# What to call a single thing of these uncountable nouns?

Tags: grammar

the words are: ***sand***, ***sugar***, ***rice***, ***salt*** and ***tea***.
as for the tea I mean the leaves not the drink.

Comment: Sorry, I sort of robo-edited your post, and I just realized what you were asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "grain" for all except "tea". That could be a "tea leaf". If it's a little piece of dried leaf, you might call it a "flake".